# Typescript strictNullChecks and arrays

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I do not fully understand Typescript's behavior with compiler option `strictNullChecks` enabled. It seems that sometimes Typescript (version 2.4.1) understands that an item in a `string[]` is a `string`, and sometimes it does not:

```js
interface MyMap {
    [key: string]: string[];
}

function f(myMap: MyMap) {
    const keys = Object.keys(myMap); // keys: string[] => Fine.
    for (let key of keys) { // key: string | undefined => Why?
        key = key as string // So a cast is needed.
        const strings = myMap[key]; // strings: string[] => Fine.
        const s = strings[0]; // s: string => Fine.

        // Error:
        // Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
        // Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        useVarArgs(...strings);
    }
}
function useVarArgs(...strings: string[]) {
}
```

Update 2017-07-14:

This strange behavior is only observed when using `downlevelIteration`. My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "target",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? You code looks fine at the [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. Version 2.4.1. Also edited question.

Comment: I tested your code on 2.4.1 and it is working correctly. `key` is string with needing to cast, and don't have the issues you mentioned.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug. I have filed an issue at Typescript's Github page: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17195

Comment: Also edited my answer to mention compiler option downlevelIteration.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error with 2.4.1, `strictNullChecks` and `downLevelIteration`.  Have you reproduced in a separate toy project?

Comment: Trying to do so revealed that this is probably no Typescript issue but a @types/core-js issue. I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I can confirm that this is not a Typescript issue. The origin of the problem are the types used for `IteratorResult<T>`. I had used `@types/core-js 0.9.36`:

```js
interface IteratorResult<T> {
    done: boolean;
    value?: T;
}
```

`value` is optional, which is technically correct, because according to [the iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol), `value` "Can be omitted when done is true." As demonstrated by my question, the optionality is not useful in practice though.

The types shipped with Typescript ("es2015" as configured in the "lib" section in `tsconfig.json`, i.e. file `lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts`) take a more pragmatic approach, obviously assuming that `value` will not be used when `done` is `true`:

```js
interface IteratorResult<T> {
    done: boolean;
    value: T;
}
```

In order to fix the problem, you can either edit `@types/core-js` or replace it with the libs shipped with Typescript. The replacement is not 100% equivalent, though - check out [this issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15140) for a discussion.